# 64-bit libjingle failing to parse login XML with expat error: ERROR_INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: c++, xml, xmpp, libjingle, expat-parser

Only upon attempting to run my login code under **64-bit**, am I getting a failure to login to [talk.google.com](http://www.google.com/talk/) for my initial tests.  32-bit works fine.

Upon enabling logging macros and siginput logging, I can see that the XML it's failing on is  this:

```
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="3D9A4487B8514DE2" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">\232\231\377
```

Inside expat I can see that there is an `XML_ERROR_INVALID_TOKEN` being thrown, but I'm not quite sure where to go from there.  Sometimes it makes it to an actual login but dies shortly after.  It appears to be relatively random, but always dies within the first 10 responses or so.  I recognize that the junk data at the end is what is probably causing the invalid token, but am not sure what causes it.

My initial thought was an encoding issue upon switching to **64-bit** (??), but honestly, I just don't know what would cause something like that to happen.

Here is an additional example snippet from the logs that libjingle dies on:

```
137[000:568] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Feb 21 00:01:31 2013
[000:568]    \332
[000:568]    <iq id="2" type="result">
[000:568]      <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
[000:568]        <jid>
[000:568]          snip@gmail.com/CD6FF
[000:568]        </jid>
[000:568]      </bind>
[000:568]    </iq>
<iq id="2" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>snip@gmail.com/CD6FF</jid></bind></iq>x\332Mhanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>p
```

And another:

```
[000:217]    <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="2462F624C942" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="246E4B24C942" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">\225\231\377
```

Another:

```
139[000:178] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Feb 21 00:20:52 2013
[000:178]    <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="B15C99514B664586" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="B15C99514B664586" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">\366\231\377
```

Another:

```
52[000:243] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Feb 21 00:23:44 2013
[000:243]    Q
[000:243]    <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>\261xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>Q
```

Anyone run into this type of issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a problem with the openssl 64 bit build I was using.  No idea what was wrong with the build, but all I had to do was switch to the libssl.0.9.8, and libcrypto.0.9.8 dylib versions and everything works great.

Hopefully, this will help others diagnose strange junk in SSL interactions.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that `\ddd` sequences represent octal numbers, your streams contain code points in invalid utf-8 which might be the default expected encoding for the xml data streams.

before feeding the content to the xml parser you'd have to replace the offending bytes by  numerical entities, e.g. `\231` -> `&#x99;`.

another option might be to prefix your xml data stream with a xml prolog declaring some 8bit-charset, eg. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>`.

hope it helps, regards

Comment: Expat is for sure using UTF8 by default per this snippet: https://gist.github.com/zero1zero/ea566a5bbbafdfb253a1.  XML_UNICODE is not set on my xcode project.  I have also verified that libjingle is checking for a UTF8 stream via https://gist.github.com/zero1zero/e4088d25efc9200f0993.  If we assume for a moment that there were an encoding mismatch, what mismatch would cause ascii characters to still render mostly correct like that?

Comment: the representations of ascii chars 0x00-0x7f do not differ between us-ascii and utf-8 encodings, therefore letters, digits, "programmer's symbols" should come out fine.

Comment: Exactly, which is why it is puzzling that only beginning and ends of the xml to parse is coming out incorrect.  Most of the time, it should be either completely junk or work correctly.  My current thought is centered around what problems the switch from 32 to 64-bit would produce.  I am still at a standstill on what might cause the junk bytes on the beginning and end.

Comment: the first and the last of log snippets you've posted contain junk bytes within the xml structures too - at least after crlf elimniation - which wreck the wellformedness. junk bytes at the beginning and the end might result from an alignment error. however i've no idea why the alignment should be off a single byte.

Comment: Figured it out and answered. Gave you the bounty for your assistance. Thanks!